# How to enable Google Apps chat with normal Gmail users

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-talk

I know that you must change some SV records for it to work but I have no idea which is which because Google just gives a string and GoDaddy has no idea how to input that string into their settings, they just ask for TTL, etc.

Can anybody help? I also cross-posted this to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com because I have no idea under which category it fits...

**Edit 29-11-2013**
Answer on Webmaster: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/3442

Comment: interesting, i have used my google apps as the email to chat for some time and never had any problem connecting to other users.  Could you describe the issue you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to configure SRV records, not SV records.

This page gives a good explanation of the process, with additional instructions for GoDaddy:
http://www.olark.com/gtalk/check_srv

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, that really answers what I needed. GoDaddy had absolutely no idea about it, sent me no less than five emails replying to me to search the faq and one last one to ask Google :) 

what a stupid system where enter posts your comment

also, SV was a spelling error, i know they're SRV records but thanks anyway